# How to make flutter android with my pc as an online database?

Tags: database, mongodb, flutter, dart

Is it possible to  make my pc as an online database for my personal flutter android application ? also i use mongodb, is it possible my flutter android to access my desktop mongodb through internet ?

Comment: You can make your pc a local server  server via Xampp or IIS. So a webservice is needed in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement local host on your PC and connect your app

check [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device) for more info